# Get a Telegram notification only when a word is used on a channel

Tags: bots, telegram-messenger

I'm subscribed to a Telegram channel that sometimes sends more than 20 messages a minute but I'm really interested in one or two of those messages a day.

The messages I'm interested in all will contain a particular word.

So far what I do is to mute the channel and several times during the day I go and search for that particular word.

Is there a way to get any kind of notification for this case?
Is there a bot or service that will send me a personal message when a condition like this is met?

Is my solution the only way?

<sub>for the curios the channel is https://t.me/newportal and I'm only interested in new portals for my region</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can use the [Junction Bot](https://t.me/junction_bot) - it allows you to follow channels and filter the messages - without joining the channel.**

From the bot help message:

> I can collect all posts from your favorite Telegram and Twitter channels, so you can read them like a news feed. Also you can use me inside groups and to forward one channel into another.

#### Steps:

1. Start the bot.
2. After choosing a language, send the bot the channel you're interested at - [newportal](https://t.me/newportal).
3. Send the bot a filter command, with the string that interest you:

   - `Format: /filter @channel_name mustHave text_to_pass` (get the full `/filter` command usage by sending the `/filter` command to the bot).
   - For example, send `/filter @newportal mustHave (ru)` to get only the messages with the text `(ru)` from the channel `@newportal`.
4. If you want, you can set the bot to forward those message to another channel - so in that case, you can create a new channel for your area.

**Note:** The bot help message states that it can take around 10 minutes of delay until you get the updates.

---

*Here's the full [Junction Bot FAQ](https://junction.space/faq.html)*

Comment: It says it will work for 30 days and then I should contact the admin. I guess they will ask for some fee. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: I haven't noticed that!

Comment: So was it useful/worth it?

Comment: yes. it is still working fine.

Comment: As today this still works fine while the bot from the other answer no longer works.

Comment: This bot is mostly paid now. Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: @PankajSinghal Sorry, no idea. I don't need it anymore so not following alternatives.

Comment: Can anyone explain how is this possible? I mean, you cant invite a bot over to a channel unless you're an owner of that channel. How are they doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [My Channels Bot](https://t.me/my_channels_feed_bot?start=738su0HwhJ) (@my_channels_feed_bot).

With this bot you can subscribe to all your favorite Telegram channels and receive all posts in a single place, in real time.

Also, you can add filters for each channel, or global filters, in order to receive only the posts you want.

[Here is a tutorial(Spanish)](https://youtu.be/HNX9UezPuHI) on YouTube on to use it.

Comment: I can only mark one as an answer but this works fine and it is quite simple to use.

Comment: This project closed. This answer is not valid anymore. It worked for a while but authors stop the project.